# Error when creating a SubMenu in React using NestedMenuItem

Tags: reactjs, menuitem

I am trying to add a sub menu to Menulist in react, but having a hard time.
imported 'mui-nested-menu' plug into my code using npm, Below is the snippet of what I am trying to do, I am returning the MenuList, which has submenu "sample" onhover it should show an options "test".
return (


<MenuItem value={'links'}>test

<MenuItem data-value={'links'}>test



);

but ended up having errors:
There are three common reasons you might be seeing it:

You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

I have gone through this link to verify any changes needed but I don't see any changes needed in my code as I was following the rules: https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#other-causes.

Can anyone help me here how to fix this issue.

Comment: I found root cause for the error, 1) verify if you have duplicate versions of same node. 2)Make sure you have permissions to install package 3) Make sure you are installing package in the correct project folder 4) Check the Node version is supported with this  mui-nested-item package .  5) verify Python version and also Visual Studio build tools. You should be good once you verify them all.